# Trying to make the program run while waiting for input

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter

This is the error: NameError: name 'data' is not defined

I need the 'data' variable to remain undefined while waiting for user input without the program crashing.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime as Dt

root = Tk()

user_input = Entry(root)
user_input.pack()


def get_input():
      global assign
      data = user_input.get


Dt.time(data)

myButton = Button(root, text="Enter data",command=get_input)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using `current_time`. Also don't use `while True` loops or `time.sleep` when using `tkinter` unless you know what it can do. Look at `.after` scripts

Comment: Sorry this is my first project i know it sucks but ive been trying for days to make this work could you plz help a newbie out?

Comment: Search this site for how to create a timer or how to create a clock. Hardly a week goes by that someone doesn't ask this same type of question.

Comment: Please provide your full code or a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the full error of any crashes you're getting.

Comment: sorry here is my full code

Comment: this is the error: tarttijd opvragen.py", line 47, in <module>
    Startijd = Dt.time(Uur, Min)
NameError: name 'Uur' is not defined

Comment: @Matiiss hope this makes my question more clear.

Comment: put `Dt.time(data)` in `get_time()` function at the end, also what is `assign` and why you made it global, also it should be `user_input.get()`, it is a method so you need to call it

Comment: @Matiiss i put in this get_time(Dt.time(data)) but now i get the error that get_time isnt defined

Comment: @Thatguynamedpeter I don't even understand how `get_time` is not defined, anyhow that is not what I said, I said to put the `Dt.time(data)` at the end of `get_time()` function, meaning after `data = user_input.get()` in the function definition

Comment: @Matiiss I`ve tried get_time().Dt.time(data) and all variations of that but nothing worked could you plz just show me some code

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is how to use `data` after it is defined, here is the easiest way how:

```py
def get_input():
    global assign
    data = user_input.get()  # also you need to call this
    Dt.time(data)
```

Comment: @mattiss i`m sorry what i meant was that i wanted the data variable to remain empty without the program crashing. The .get function only gets called when someone enters input and clicks on a button so data will be empty.

Comment: @Thatguynamedpeter I don't think you understand how event driven programming works, I am pretty sure that you need to put `Dt.time()` inside some function, anyways, what are you even trying to do?

Comment: You`re right i infact do not understand how it works and just had to look up what it actually means, i just halfway finished the course how to automate the boring stuff with python and realise now that i got a bit too ambitious in attempting to make an app from scratch that would automaticly shut off whatever i was on my pc when the timer got off sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: Sorry that i`m asking but do you maybe have some advice on what i need to learn first before i can make apps like that

Comment: @Thatguynamedpeter well you really need to understand event-driven programming. There usually is some event like user clicking a button, that event then calls a function that executes something. It isn't really that hard to make such an app, you just need to get the process id from cmd (on windows), for that the simplest is to look at what `os` module offers or look at some `cmd` commands that could help you stop some running process. The time thing is also quite simple, just have some `.after()` loop that checks the current time and if time is met then it kills the process using its id.